# Importing custom library from different folder path in python

Tags: python, anaconda, python-import, spyder, python-importlib

I have the following folder structure:

`A/fold1/MyLib/package/`

in which I have an `__init__.py` file and a file with the functions I need, let's call it `file.py`.

When I work from this path:

`A/fold1/myProject/script.py`

I try to import it but it looks like this library can't be found.

I have already worked, and it was fine when I had a structure like this:

`A/fold1/myProject/package/file.py`

where `package` contained also the `__init__.py` file.

I also got suggestions from the Spyder IDE.
What I used, to make it work was to import like this:

```py
if packagePath not in sys.path:

    sys.path.append(packagePath)

import package.file as f
```

But currently it doesn't work, and I don't even get the suggestions from the Spyder IDE.

Is there a way to import from the specified structure?

I wanted a folder with all my functions, and if possible to have it in this folder and not between the hundreds of libraries of python.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using the full-path in ``packagePath``? From your description it seems that you have moved the module into a "MyLib" folder outside "myProject".

Comment: don't use spyder for developement, use pycharm, to solve your problem, you need to make a base folder and acccording to base folder you need to import in files. lets say A is base folder, then to import file.py in script.py you need to use `from A.fold1.MyLib.package.file import function` use it like this

Comment: thanks prashant! @prasanth yes I've moved it outside to make it like general for any other project.

Comment: Just a hunch: can you delete all ``*.pyc`` files in ``myProject`` and other directories. In the past I have tried this, successfully, to get python to refresh a module.